# C# asp.net control chart load from drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp drop down list control on my page, with a list of devices. I am attempting to get the selected value and pass it to a stored procedure to get data back to load into my chart. but I cannot figure out why its not firing off. I put a break point right at the beginning of the selected index changed method but it never gets there. I choose and item in the list but nothing happens. I have already tested the stored procedure and that is ok.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DeviceDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RunningProcessCpuAndMemByHour", sqlConn);

    sqlConn.Open();

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Device", DeviceDropDownList.SelectedValue));

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    CpuAndMemoryByHourGraph.Series[0].YValueMembers = "cpu";
    CpuAndMemoryByHourGraph.Series[1].YValueMembers = "mem_percent";
    CpuAndMemoryByHourGraph.Series[0].XValueMember = "process";

    CpuAndMemoryByHourGraph.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
    CpuAndMemoryByHourGraph.DataBind();

    sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might sound silly but did you actually postback? If you wanna fire postback whenever ddl change you need to enable `autopostback`.

Comment: Hi! You know you were right, I completely overlooked that. Thanks for catching it!